# How to get working React.lazy/Suspense with dynamic imports?

Tags: reactjs

I know I can lazy import and render with Suspense and all that stuff, but what happens in scenarios like this:

I have an index file that exports all files from that folder:

```js
export { default as Reactjs } from './Reactjs';
export { default as Bootstrap } from './Bootstrap';
export { default as Cypress } from './Cypress';
export { default as Firebase } from './Firebase';

and so on...
```

In the router file i have imported like this:

```js
import * as Components from './components';
```

Then, I have a list of the routes to render:

```js
const routes = [
  'Reactjs',
  'ReactRouter',
  'Redux',
  'Materialui',
  'Socketio',

  ... and so on
];
```

And this is the code i'm reusing for each route:

```js
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={path} component={Frontend} />
      {routes.map((route) => (
        <Route
          key={route}
          path={`${path}/${route.toLowerCase()}`}
          component={Components[route]}
          exact
          {...props}
        />
      ))}
    </Switch>
```

In this scenario all files are bundled, and I want to avoid this using React.lazy

I tried to do it but routes are not gettind bundled, when you navigates to any of those routes, not error thrown, just no content, the component is never rendered.

**I know could just import lazyly in router component each one and manually add all routes and it will work, but this project is growing quickly and looking for a generic solution, any ideas?**

## SOLUTION

The point here is to use `render` method instead of `component`. As suggested with a utils func is the way it works.

Final Code:

```js
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as Components from './components';
import Frontend from './Frontend';

const routes = [
  'Reactjs',
  'ReactRouter',
  'Redux',
  'Materialui',
  'Socketio',
  'HTML5',
  'CSS3',
  'Victory',
  'Firebase',
  'Cypress',
  'Jest',
  'Enzyme',
  'StyledComponents',
  'Sass',
  'Javascript',
];
const path = '/developer/frontend';

const renderLazyComponents = (WrappedComponent, props) => (
  <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
    <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  </Suspense>
);

const FrontendRoutes = (props) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={path} component={Frontend} />
      {routes.map((route) => (
        <Route
          key={route}
          path={`${path}/${route.toLowerCase()}`}
          render={(props) => renderLazyComponents(Components[route], props)}
          exact
          {...props}
        />
      ))}
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default FrontendRoutes;
```

previous zip:

```js
  496.93 KB (-878 B)  build/static/js/2.4e310625.chunk.js
  28.2 KB (-7.41 KB)  build/static/js/main.fa528c14.chunk.js
  725 B               build/static/js/runtime-main.3ce8a40d.js
  574 B               build/static/css/main.13004e90.chunk.css
```

next zip:

```js
  497.9 KB (+986 B)    build/static/js/2.376eba4d.chunk.js
  34.98 KB (+6.78 KB)  build/static/js/main.94a280ad.chunk.js
  2.56 KB              build/static/js/3.b1f8eb5c.chunk.js
  1.26 KB (+567 B)     build/static/js/runtime-main.0ae647e3.js
  574 B                build/static/css/main.13004e90.chunk.css
  212 B                build/static/js/16.1903fd99.chunk.js
  208 B                build/static/js/11.adc04e6c.chunk.js
  206 B                build/static/js/12.c2f29dcb.chunk.js
  204 B                build/static/js/15.654cac3a.chunk.js
  204 B                build/static/js/17.6a7c5409.chunk.js
  204 B                build/static/js/4.e5aeca49.chunk.js
  204 B                build/static/js/8.e22f9199.chunk.js
  203 B                build/static/js/13.2bc7ba5b.chunk.js
  203 B                build/static/js/6.4d3d0771.chunk.js
  203 B                build/static/js/9.59059160.chunk.js
  202 B                build/static/js/7.39b3929b.chunk.js
  201 B                build/static/js/14.d7fd54d7.chunk.js
  201 B                build/static/js/5.0c63c3bb.chunk.js
  200 B                build/static/js/10.5c3037d5.chunk.js
```

Comment: At what point is Lazy's technique really applied? In addition, what was the benefit of this performance since both the number and size of the files increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple way, you can do lazy loading by below code snippet:

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <OtherComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if you want it to make genric, I would suggest to do in `App.js` like I did in my project.

```
     const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

    <div className="app-body">
                            <Switch>

                                <Route
                                    path={routingPath}
                                    render={props =>
                                        ComponentUtils.getSuspenseFulLazyComponent(
                                            <OtherLandingPage
                                                {...props}

                                            />
                                        )
                                    }
                                />
                       ....
                       ....
                       ....

</Switch>
```

Now in `ComponentUtils.js` file, write this generic function:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload'
import BlockUi from 'react-block-ui'

export default class ComponentUtils {
    static getSuspenseFulLazyComponent(component, shouldLazyLoad, lazyLoadOffset) {
        return (
            <Suspense
                fallback={
                    <BlockUi tag="div" blocking={true}>
                        {' '}
                    </BlockUi>
                }
            >
                {!shouldLazyLoad ? component : <LazyLoad offset={100}>{component}</LazyLoad>}
            </Suspense>
        )
    }
}
```

I hope this solution can help you to find your way!!!!

Comment: Thx @sidverma, i'll try now your approach. In your example you are using named import `OtherComponent` will it work with dinamyc? I will try and get it back.

Comment: `OtherComponent` is just an example where u can put ur original components which u want to load(yeah dynamically).
If you are using Next js , then probably try like this: import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

`const OtherComponent = dynamic(
  () => import("../../{filename}"),
  { ssr: false }
);`

Comment: Sorry I can't get the point here without importing each one, and then passing again each one to getSuspenseFulLazyComponent

Comment: In `App.js` you have to import  all your main components like this `const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));` 

then as your project is big then obviously you would have many `<Routes>` . So to load those component dynamically you can write a `util.js` function. In that parametric function, you can pass the component name and other things to lazy load or not etc... That's what the Util function is meant to be

Comment: Thx sidverma you gave me the main idea, use `render` method instead of `component` in route, i will update the question with the final code